# Keep interval Observable running in Java

Tags: java, rx-java, intervals

I am new to threading in Java and was wondering how I can keep the following Observable running,

```
private void init() {
    System.out.println("Running...");

    Observable o = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(o -> serverService.listServers("all"))
            .retryWhen(o -> o.flatMap(s -> Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .subscribe(serverModels -> System.out.println("onNext"),
                    e -> System.out.println("ERROR " + e),
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed"));
}
```

If I call this method from main(), the process exits immediately. How do I refrain from a process exit?

Comment: The observable doesn't exit immediately, but if your main exits immediately, then this observable will stop when the JVM stops.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Makes sense. Is there an elegant way to prevent this from happening? I'd like the observable to running for an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleeping can cause bugs.  Instead checkout the blockingSubscribe operator.